# Issue with FTX US API POST Request

Tags: python, api, rest, authentication, ethereum

I have looked through the FTX API documentation found here: https://docs.ftx.us/#overview

And I've looked at the example code found in this repo: https://github.com/ftexchange/ftx/tree/master/rest

I am hitting **POST** Request on **/wallet/withdrawals**
but I am getting

**{"success":false,"error":"Not logged in: Invalid signature","errorCode":"not_logged_in"}**

Here is my Code:

```
        resp = requests.get('https://otc.ftx.com/api/time')
        ftx_t = resp.json()
        time = ftx_t['result']
        date_format = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
        unix_time = datetime.datetime.timestamp(date_format)
        ts = unix_time * 1000
        # ts = int(time.time() * 1000)
        request = Request('**POST**', '**https://ftx.us/api/wallet/withdrawals**')  # To make withdrawas
        prepared1 = request.prepare()
        body = {
            "coin": "USDT",   # coin to withdraw
            "size": 0,  # amount to withdraw
            "address": "***************"  # address to send to
        }
        signature_payload1 = f'{ts}{prepared1.method}{prepared1.path_url}'.encode()
        signature1 = hmac.new('**SECRET KEY**'.encode(), signature_payload1, 'sha256').hexdigest()

        prepared1.headers[f'FTXUS-KEY'] = '**API KEY**'
        prepared1.headers[f'FTXUS-SIGN'] = signature1
        prepared1.headers[f'FTXUS-TS'] = str(ts)
        prepared1.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        prepared1.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
        
        data1 = json.dumps(body).encode()


        res10 = requests.post('https://ftx.us/api/wallet/withdrawals', data=data1, headers=prepared1.headers)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode your data for sending post requests and add this encoded data in the body as well as when you are requesting a POST request.

This might help:

Before calling your `signature1` variable you need to add the following:

```
prepared1.body = json.dumps(body).encode()
if prepared1.body:
   signature_payload1 += prepared1.body
```

And in your POST request method, add the body in your **Data Attribute**:

```
res10 = requests.post('https://ftx.us/api/wallet/withdrawals', data=prepared1.body, headers=prepared1.headers)
```

Here I have edited the code for you:

```
 resp = requests.get('https://otc.ftx.com/api/time')
            ftx_t = resp.json()
            time = ftx_t['result']
            date_format = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
            unix_time = datetime.datetime.timestamp(date_format)
            ts = (unix_time * 1000)
            request = Request('POST', 'https://ftx.us/api/wallet/withdrawals')  # To make withdrawas
            prepared1 = request.prepare()
            signature_payload1 = f'{ts}{prepared1.method}{prepared1.path_url}'.encode()
            body = {
                "coin": "USDT",  # coin to withdraw
                "size": 0,  # amount to withdraw
                "address": "***************"  # address to send to
            }
            prepared1.body = json.dumps(body).encode()
            if prepared1.body:
                signature_payload1 += prepared1.body
            signature1 = hmac.new(SECRET KEY.encode(), signature_payload1,
                                  'sha256').hexdigest()

            prepared1.headers[f'FTXUS-KEY'] = API KEY
            prepared1.headers[f'FTXUS-SIGN'] = signature1
            prepared1.headers[f'FTXUS-TS'] = str(ts)
            prepared1.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
            prepared1.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
            res10 = requests.post('https://ftx.us/api/wallet/withdrawals', data=prepared1.body, headers=prepared1.headers)
```

You can check these for reference:

https://blog.ftx.com/blog/api-authentication/

https://github.com/ftexchange/ftx/issues/10